# Can I substitute "stress" with "emphasize" or "accentuate" in the following sentence?

Tags: vocabulary

The sentence is:
**"I cannot *stress* enough how much music matters in my life."**

Can I replace **stress** with **emphasize** or **accentuate**?

Are there any differences among these three *synonyms; stress, emphasize, accentuate*?

Comment: You [*can* use "accentuate".](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22cannot+accentuate+enough%22) But given [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cannot+stress+enough%2Ccannot+emphasise+enough%2Ccannot+emphasize+enough%2Ccannot+accentuate+enough&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccan%20not%20stress%20enough%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20not%20emphasise%20enough%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20not%20emphasize%20enough%3B%2Cc0), why would you *want* to?

Comment: (You obviously know all three words are effectively ***synonyms***, since you say that in your question text.)

Comment: In fact I would avoid the use of the word **stress** in this context, because the idea that came to me when I first read the sentence, was that music is causing you stress.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that all three words work equally well in this context. 'Stress' and 'emphasize' are more commonly used in this construction than 'accentuate'.

Accentuate is used more often to describe aesthetic effects, such as when you say

> You earrings accentuate the lines of your jaw.
>   The color of the walls accentuates the red in the carpet.